# Removing Copy from UIMenucontroller not working in IOS 5?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I subclassed the UIWebView and i written this function

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender { 

    if (action == @selector(copy:)){
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(_define:)){
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;

}
```

I can be able to hide all the action other than Copy. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,